# git can't open editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, editor

I'm trying to set up my git to work with an editor, following best advices from SO and manual, but for some reason git doesn't like it.

I did "git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad\notepad.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"

and now I have those lines in my global `.gitconfig` (`C:\Users\me\.gitconfig`):

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

looks good, but when i do `git rebase`, for example editor won't open and rebase does nothing basically:

```
D:\Work>git rebase --interactive 5beacd
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Warning: 'm' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'u' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'l' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 't' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'i' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'I' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'o' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'b' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'e' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'P' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.

Version:          Code 1.60.2 (7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e, 2021-09-22T12:00:31.514Z)
OS Version:       Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601
CPUs:             Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz (8 x 4008)
Memory (System):  15.94GB (2.70GB free)
VM:               0%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     --crash-reporter-id 09f6bede-c370-4dc4-8c9c-78701a83cb24
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                  enabled
                  gpu_compositing:            enabled
                  multiple_raster_threads:    enabled_on
                  oop_rasterization:          enabled
                  opengl:                     enabled_on
                  rasterization:              enabled
                  skia_renderer:              enabled_on
                  video_decode:               enabled
                  vulkan:                     disabled_off
                  webgl:                      enabled
                  webgl2:                     enabled

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    0       94   15840  code main
    0        9   13276     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-update-user-x64\CodeSetup-stable-ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea.exe /verysilent /update="C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-update-user-x64\CodeSetup-stable-ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea.flag" /nocloseapplications /mergetasks=runcode,!desktopicon,!quicklaunchicon
    0       27   35088       "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\is-RFB26.tmp\CodeSetup-stable-ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea.tmp" /SL5="$3304A2,78576488,828416,C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-update-user-x64\CodeSetup-stable-ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea.exe" /verysilent /update="C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-update-user-x64\CodeSetup-stable-ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea.flag" /nocloseapplications /mergetasks=runcode,!desktopicon,!quicklaunchicon
    0      751   17908     window (.gitconfig - braingames - Visual Studio Code)
    1      103    3176       extensionHost
    0       75   12464         "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html-language-features\server\dist\node\htmlServerMain" --node-ipc --clientProcessId=3176
    0       44   22920         "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json-language-features\server\dist\node\jsonServerMain" --node-ipc --clientProcessId=3176
    0       20   40264         "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\css-language-features\server\dist\node\cssServerMain" --node-ipc --clientProcessId=3176
    0       77   42620         electron_node tsserver.js
    0       25   45712           electron_node typingsInstaller.js typesMap.js
    0       65   52184         electron_node tsserver.js
    0       10    6568       watcherService
    0       35   15920       searchService
    0       57   36104     shared-process
    0      427   32528       ptyHost
    0        5    9404         winpty-process
    0        3   61152           C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
    0       49   45644             "d:\Program Files\dart-sass\\src\dart.exe"  "d:\Program Files\dart-sass\\src\sass.snapshot" --watch .:..\css --style compressed --no-source-map
    0        4   27876         winpty-process
    0        3   34888           C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
    0        5   53524         winpty-process
    0        4   63456           C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
    0        3   14264             git  rebase --interactive 5beacf48f80f77b0a52273f1bffea54097324985
    0        8   30900               git.exe  rebase --interactive 5beacf48f80f77b0a52273f1bffea54097324985
    0        7   40316                 sh -c "'C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin \"$@\"" "'C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin" D:/Work/bg/braingames/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
    0       61   14956                   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin D:/Work/bg/braingames/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
    0       10   30280                     crashpad-handler
    0       13   37552                     gpu-process
    0        4   55848         winpty-process
    0        2    5400           C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
    0        6   36596             mysql  -u root -p
    0      274   42516     gpu-process
    0        5   48004     crashpad-handler
    0       16   59432     utility

Workspace Stats:
|  Window (.gitconfig - work - Visual Studio Code)
|    Folder (work): 5448 files
|      File types: txt(2124) php(1158) gif(529) png(275) html(168) zip(139)
|                  js(98) css(69) sass(48) svg(31)
|      Conf files: launch.json(1) settings.json(1) tasks.json(1)
|      Launch Configs: pwa-chrome


Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/cert.
```

I tried to change slashes to make it similar to other .gitconfig lines - no luck.

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

Comment: You are using options meant for notepad++ to VSCode. Try `...\code.exe --wait`

Comment: @LeGEC that was exactly the problem. If you make an answer from it I will accept it.